# have to be careful

Tags: meaning, infinitives, ambiguity

a. It is something that you have to be careful to notice.

I suppose one meaning of (a) is:

1. You have to be careful and notice that thing.

But could it also mean

2. If you notice that, then that means that you are careful.
   ?

I think the same ambiguity exists in:

b. You have to be careful to notice that.

Would you agree with that?

Many thanks.

Comment: You are right: it is ambiguous.

Answer (score 3):

Yes ***careful*** like vast numbers of words in English has different senses in which it is used.

If I say "You must be careful to switch off the gas", it means that it is unsafe to leave it switched on - and therefore care is needed on your part in remembering to switch it off.

But if I say "In order putt your golf ball you have to be careful to avoid the bunker", it means that care is required in order to perform something successfully.

"Take care" means something quite different to "Care is necessary..."

Ambiguity can arise with something like "You have to be careful to see what's going on". As you point out it can mean two quite different things.

Comment: Thank you so much WS2, How about: 'That is a car you have to spend a lot of money to own." and ''That is a place where you have to dare to go' I think the first one is ambiguous and the second one isn't. Would you agree with that?

Comment: @azz They both involve relative clauses and both are grammatical, though a bit cumbersome to read. How about *That is a car requiring a lot of money to own* and *That is a place which requires daring to visit*.  Strictly speaking, on this site, if you want to clarify something completely different, you should set up a new question, on a fresh page.